# Adding principalsQuery in webUI doesn't allow spaces

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jaas

I'm currently doing a school assignment where we need to setup JAAS so it is import i use JAAS and not another security module.

When i'm trying to add: principalsQuery=select Password from Principals where PrincipalID=? to my authentication module in the WebUI I get invalid format error since it doesn't allow spaces(it accepts when there are no spaces).

Whenever i google the problem i see the standalone.xml configured with module options that include spaces. I've tried to include it in my standalone.xml (see below) but it won't work and the webUI keeps giving me the error.

```
<authentication>
       <login-module code="test" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJindiName" value="java:/MySqlDS"/>
            <module-option name="principalQuery" value="SELECT password from user where username = ?" />
        </login-module>
</authentication>
```

my datasource is configured as follows

```
 <datasource jndi-name="java:/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Kwetter</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>root</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

The DsJindiName works and is accepted by the login-module. But the principalQuery keeps giving me the error. My thinking is that the legacy security is not correctly support anymore any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I've figured out I needed to use Elytron to use JAAS. Using this [guide](http://docs.wildfly.org/15/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#set-up-and-configure-authentication-for-applications)
a problem occurs at the last step, the jbos-web.xml  doesn't accept Elytron application security domains and errors at compiling. However, when you set the standard security domain in undertow it'll build and work like expected.